# printing variables in GDB seems to change code behavior?

Tags: c++, gdb, 32bit-64bit

I'm debugging a large, ancient, piece of code that we just upgraded the OS/driver for, the entire thing is running 32 bit.  The original developers of the code are long gone and much of it is still a black box to me.

I'm running it on the debugger.  I narrowed down on a particular if statement within a larger loop, I need the 'else' part of the for loop to run to update some variables, but it was never running; implying that the variable that is being checked in the 'if' statement is always true.

Eventually I stepped into the method call (a simple getter on a private boolean) and printed the content of the variable.  When I print the variable it is false, and the 'else' method will be entered when I return.

To experiment I've tried allowing the loop to run for 10 minutes, the 'else' method is never entered (as indicated by a breakpoint not being hit).  Then when I print the variable being checked it's false and the variable is entered.  It doesn't matter how long I let it run, or how many times I break and continue before printing the variable, the same pattern holds, I enter the 'else' method IFF I print the content of the variable that is being checked first.

To rule out some sort of datarace I've tried sitting at the breakpoint in question for the length of time it takes to do a print statement, a delay without a print doesn't result in entering the 'else' method.

What could cause such an odd behavior?  Since we had issues with different architectures, running a 32 bit program on a 64 bit OS and, more importantly, the driver that it uses was not tested for 32 bit for years until they recompiled the driver for me under a 32 bit architecture, which would make me suspect the driver except that particular line of code that is misbehaving isn't touching the driver in any way.  Still I suspect some sort of overflow or underflow may be happening due to a confusion caused by trying to force an old 32 bit program to run.

However, even assuming this could cause such an odd behavior, I don't know how to confirm if that is happening or otherwise debug a program where the act of looking at it changes it's behavior.  I'd love any tip on what could cause such a problem or how I could move forward with debugging it.

Dammit Jim I'm a programmer, not a Quantum Mechanic!

Comment: That would most likely be an undefined behavior example. But it would be hard to tell you what it is. Try running through valgrind/asan/any other undefined behavior detection tools which are there. You do compile it with maximum warning level, right?

Comment: Seems like you may have UB. Perhaps showing the code near the problematic `if` would allow us to spot the mistake.

Comment: Changing, adding, or removing lines of innocuous code and having your program behave differently is an indication of undefined behavior.  One thing you should **not** do is try and play games with removing and adding these lines.  Leave the code exactly as it is that reproduces the problem, and fix the problem.  If you remove, add, or change these lines expecting the program now "works", you are in worse shape because 1) you've masked the bug, you haven't fixed it and 2) you no longer have a chance to fix it because the bug is covered up.

Comment: Are there multiple threads involved?  This sounds like a classic data race.  Could be that printing the value forces a cache or register to get flushed out to memory where a subsequent read can pick it up.

Comment: If the address whose values you read from is not RAM but a hardware register than reading it may change the value.

Comment: You say, "... except that particular line of code that is misbehaving isn't touching the driver in any way." You do not know what code is misbehaving. It could be the driver. That said, I have seen similar behavior result from a previous function call returning a reference to a local variable. Could that "simple getter" possibly be "getting" from an object that was destructed when a function returned?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the "simple getter".  Take note of the address it is getting from. Is it a stack address, and if so, is it a bogus address from the presently unused part of the stack? If so, the print routine is using that address when it is called and pushes its way onto the stack. If it's not that, your object is probably using heap memory through a dangling pointer.

Comment: Are you still here?